# Unable to Connect to MySQL local server 3306 in Power BI

Tags: mysql, tcp, powerbi

I was about to start a Project using MySQL and Power BI for creating a dashboard but I faced a severe challenge. When I was going to connect MySQL database in Power BI, I faced an error like:

> Microsoft SQL: A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.)"

I am not able to find any solution for this over the internet.

Comment: Are you accessing the Server from another network?

Comment: No no I am using the same network.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I had the exact same error and I got that resolved. So you'll need to ensure that the **MySQL connector net is installed**. And I made the mistake of importing the JAR file instead.

DO NOT DO THAT. Download and Install the msi package (If you're using windows) from this link. [Connector Net Download Link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Once that's installed.

1. Close Power BI if it's opened. (Basically restart Power BI).
2. Start the SQL Server. I'm using XAMPP.
   [Check this screenshot of the XAMPP Window with the MySQL server started.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFVpJ.png)
3. Open Power BI and click on "Get Data" option. That will open up a pop up window asking you to choose all the different data sources.
4. **Now comes the 2nd important point. Ensure you select "MySQL Database".** [Check this image for the MySQL Data source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZe72.png)
5. Click on "connect", and in the server field type in the **IP address and the port number.** and also specify the database name. [Check this image for the input fields.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQLw5.png)
6. Click "ok" and if all goes well, you should see all the tables under the database in the "Navigator" window. [I have selected 2 tables called "city" and "sdetails" under the database "school".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEs5L.png)

And from here, you can choose to "Load" or "Transform Data" and get on with visualizing it.

---

> **Note :**

> **1. If power BI throws up an error window asking for credentials choose "Database Credentials". By default "Windows Credentials" would be selected.**

> **2. Here, provide the username and password for your SQL Connection. The same credentials which you would use in your code based connections.**

> **3. For XAMPP the default username would be "root" and the password would be an empty field.**

> **4. Save the database credentials and try connecting to the database again and it should work.**

---